# Rename files with a sequence number on a per-folder basis

Tags: powershell, sequence, directory

I need to number the files in a lot of folders.

I used the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.* | ForEach-Object -Begin { $count = 1 } -Process { Rename-Item $_ -NewName "image_$count.jpg"; $count++ }
```

It works, but the problem is that the numbering is continuing between the folders.

For example:

```
\folder1
image_1.jpg
image_2.jpg
image_3.jpg

\folder2
image_4.jpg
image_5.jpg
image_6.jpg

...
```

What I need is to stop the number count when each folder ends and the rename starts from number 1 in the next folder.

Thanks.

Comment: in the process block...if($_.PsIsContainer){$count = 1}

Comment: @EBGreen That might not work if there are more nested folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
Here is a better answer after all the comments

```
$directoryName = $null
$count = 1
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Include *.* | 
ForEach-Object {
    if ($directoryName -eq $null -or $directoryName -ne $_.DirectoryName) {
        $directoryName = $_.DirectoryName
        $count = 1
    }
Rename-Item $_.fullname "image_$count.jpg" -WhatIf
$count++
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. But I got an error:
Cannot rename item at “imageABC.jpg” because item does not exist.

Comment: This is happening with all files. The file exists but the rename isn't working.

Comment: Line:4 character:61
+             ForEach-Object -Begin { $count = 1 } -Process { Rename-Item $_ -NewN

Comment: You might need -NewName ("image_" +$count + ".jpg")

Comment: @ HeedfulCrayon You can access the property of a variable without brackets which can sometimes cause a problem if you build a string as per your answer. Since you have an integer store in the variable it shouldn't be a issue in this case. But I find my method most predictable and reliable regardless of the value of the variable.

Comment: Hi, I changed the $_ with $_.FullName and it almost works. Some folders starts correctly with 1 (image_1.jpg) as first item but others starts with 100 (image_100.jpg).

Comment: @HeedfulCrayon No, they are at same level. I don't get exactly why, but it is almost there.

Comment: @JohnAdam1 I don't know if you ever got this working, but you could try initializing `$count` to 1 before looping through each item. I edited my answer to reflect this

Comment: @HeedfulCrayon Hey man. It's working now, I think it was a bug of some kind. Because in some folders there were duplicate files (same size but with different names), I removed all duplicate files from the folders and your script worked as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hash table whose keys are the files' respective parent directory path to maintain per-directory sequence numbers:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Include *.* | 
 ForEach-Object { $ht = @{} } { 
   $nextNum = ++$ht[$_.DirectoryName]
   Rename-Item $_.fullname "image_$nextNum.jpg" -WhatIf
 }
```

<sup>If there's concern over the hash table growing too large, you can insert the following statement before the `$nextNum = ...` line, which ensures that only ever 1 entry is maintained:

`if (-not $ht[$_.DirectoryName]) { $ht.Clear() }`</sup>

Note that `++$ht[$_.DirectoryName]` takes advantage of the fact that hash-table entries are created on demand, with a `$null` value, and that applying `++` to a `$null` L-value results in `1`.